# Is there a way to make a kubernetes service name set as Prometheus Job name automatically?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

How can I make my Kubernetes service name set as the Prometheus Job name automatically? I mean to say that is there a possible way to get a new service created in K8s made automatically as a target in Prometheus configuration? In Kubernetes, I will like to deploy my application as set of services.

For every service there could be more than 1 pod associated.

MApping could be done like:

- Kubernetes services to Prometheus Jobs
- K8s Pods to instances in Prometheus Job

But I really don't know if this is feasible with some Configuration changes in Prometheus. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

If this is not possible, do I need to write create explicitly Prometheus job  in the Prometheus Configuration file every time before deployment.

Comment: If you want to automate deployment of multiple resources into your cluster look at helm charts

Comment: I believe helm charts will ease the deployment. But my question is primarily on "how to automatically create a Prometheus Job based on service name"

Answer (score 0):

You will typically want metrics per pod, as you would normally have when using regular nodes instead of containers/pods.

Using [this Prometheus configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml) you will get a target for every pod that's running on the cluster automatically. This is the important part

```
# Example scrape config for pods
#
# The relabeling allows the actual pod scrape endpoint to be configured via the
# following annotations:
#
# * `prometheus.io/scrape`: Only scrape pods that have a value of `true`
# * `prometheus.io/path`: If the metrics path is not `/metrics` override this.
# * `prometheus.io/port`: Scrape the pod on the indicated port instead of the
# pod's declared ports (default is a port-free target if none are declared).
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

As explained in the comments above, this is configured so pods that contains the `prometheus.io/scrape` set to true, will be scraped by Prometheus, becoming a target. Pods will then need to have a metrics endpoint exposing metrics in the Prometheus format. You can use the `prometheus.io/path` and `prometheus.io/port` to configure where Prometheus will look for the metrics on your pod.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I completely understand the concept of automatic pod discovery and mapping to Prometheus target. But I am looking forward for automatic job creation in Prometheus, that new job created must be same as my K8s Service name. Is this really possible?